# Progress upwards?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

I'm looking for a somewhat sequential list of books to learn math beyond calculus at home. I've taken calc 3 and am going further but I'm having a lot of trouble nailing down a real order of things now to practice on my own. I've tried kind of figuring it out from uni class catalogues online and things like that but since I don't get a syllabus I don't get the texts listing. Anyway, it can be textbooks, those little dover books, websites etc., but I'm looking for books that lay down foundations for higher math and delve into that math itself in a progression. There are other things I feel like I should have a better foundation on that would apply to the math I've taken so far.

Any and all help would be much appreciated. I wouldn't mind some recommendations in the calc department either. Some of the things I'm interested in learning more about include linear algebra, combinatorics, number theory, logic, and complex numbers.

Sorry there isn't an actual problem here.

Edit: Didn't know someone else could change my tags but things I know I'm looking for combinatorics, number theory, linear algebra, logic, more in depth calculus (had a garbage textbook), complex analysis to start.

Comment: Is there a particular branch you are interested in or would like to avoid? Depending on your level of comfort, possibly the next logical step is an introductory text for proofs, such as an introduction to analysis text.

Comment: Funny thing, I can't narrow it down til I know more about what I like! So far I'm curious about everything I hear about which is completely directionless and useless but it does mean that just about any suggestion is perfect. Intro texts are what I'm looking for but for specific titles and possible with follow ups. I tend to find things that are way beyond my current level which is also feeding the lack of direction. Definitely number theory.

Comment: a book I like for self-learning some of the fundamentals is Chapter Zero by Schumacher. I recall it being a bit on the expensive side though.

Comment: Download Cambridge/Oxford syllabi. There's a lot of book references there and also an order for studying them.

Comment: I like Kelley's _General Topology_, but take care: he uses utterly idiosyncratic definitions of some terms relating to orderings. Munkres' _Topology_ is good, but not always as exciting.

Comment: @katansi: If you prefer easier introductory texts to get your feet wet, I'll suggest Wade's [Introduction to Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Analysis-Edition-William-Wade/dp/0131453335/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1371568726&sr=8-1&keywords=introduction+to+analysis+wade+3rd) (this is the 3rd edition, which isn't significantly different from the fourth but is significantly cheaper). If you prefer a little bit more advanced introduction, I'd suggest Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

Comment: Thanks all. I will get on finding these. 

@Clayton I'm trying to start from beginner in these things but then go as far as my brain can handle.